# Linear layout add view not getting full width

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have `LinearLayout` in that I have `RadioGroup` in `RadioGroup`  I am adding layout dynamically using `addview()` method of `LinearLayout`. I am able to add view but my view not getting full width.

here is my code

```
  radiogroup_ans.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    radiogroup_ans.removeAllViews();
    radiogroup_ans.clearCheck();

    for (int i = 0; i < subjectDetailMain.getSubjectdetail().get(0).getPackageDetailArrayList().size(); i++)
    {
        LinearLayout lnr=new LinearLayout(this);

        RadioButton rb_answer = new RadioButton(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rb_answer.setLayoutParams(p);
        rb_answer.setId(i);
        rb_answer.setTag(i);

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.packagelist_layout,(ViewGroup) null);
        p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
        v.setLayoutParams(p);
        lnr.addView(rb_answer);
        lnr.addView(v);
        radiogroup_ans.addView(lnr);


    }
```

here is output hows its looks

[image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiZHpZTGMtZVllVjQ)

here is image how i want it

[image2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRielpWLXJjcF9XVm8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinearLayout lnr=new LinearLayout(this);
LayoutParams LParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lnr.setLayoutParams(LParams);
```

Set Layout params to lnr also

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. I hope it will help

```
 radiogroup_ans.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    radiogroup_ans.removeAllViews();
    radiogroup_ans.clearCheck();

    for (int i = 0; i < subjectDetailMain.getSubjectdetail().get(0).getPackageDetailArrayList().size(); i++)
    {
        LinearLayout lnr=new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //add this line
        lnr.setLayoutParams(parms); //add this line

        RadioButton rb_answer = new RadioButton(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rb_answer.setLayoutParams(p);
        rb_answer.setId(i);
        rb_answer.setTag(i);

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.packagelist_layout,(ViewGroup) null);
        p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
        v.setLayoutParams(p);
        lnr.addView(rb_answer);
        lnr.addView(v);
        radiogroup_ans.addView(lnr);


    }
```